# Scala dataframe: replace spaces with null value using regexp_replace

Tags: scala, null, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace white-spaces with a `null` value using `regexp_replace` in Scala. However, all variations I have tried do not arrive at the expected output:

```
+---+-----+
| Id|col_1|
+---+-----+
|  0| null|
|  1| null|
+---+-----+
```

I had a go at it which looks like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "   "),
  (1, null),
  (2, "hello"))).toDF("Id", "col_1")

val test = df.withColumn("col_1", regexp_replace(df("col_1"), "^\\s*", lit(Null)))
test.filter("col_1 is null").show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use `regexp_replace` won't work as the result will simply be a string with the matched substring replaced with another provided substring.  You can use [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) instead for a regex equality check in a `when/other` clause as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (0, "   "),
  (1, null),
  (2, "hello"),
  (3, "")
).toDF("Id", "col_1")

df.withColumn("col_1",
  when($"col_1" === regexp_extract($"col_1", "(^\\s*$)", 1), null).
    otherwise($"col_1")
).show
// +---+-----+
// | Id|col_1|
// +---+-----+
// |  0| null|
// |  1| null|
// |  2|hello|
// |  3| null|
// +---+-----+
```